# regExp with accept all special char least one number one uppercase one alphabet in any format

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$!`~^()_-{}|<>?,+=:"/\\])[a-zA-Z0-9@#%$!`~^()_-{}|<>?,+=:"/\\]{8,16}$
```

I need least one special char one number one uppercase one alphabet in any format is not working properly, **Note** I need to allow all special char I used this debugger to generate the [the regExp](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HsYwSHX3Kq59ydPz)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: what does it do? what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Hi @Aaru, This question is missing a proper description of the problem and a question. Would you mind extending the question? Thanks

Comment: At a cursory glance, your regex looks either right or very much on the right track.  That being said, you never told us what isn't working.  Please edit your question and make it complete.

Comment: thank for your reply I want to know the above regExp is correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if I escape the `/` characters like this `\/`.

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$!`~^()_-{}|<>?,+=:"\/\\])[a-zA-Z0-9@#%$!`~^()_-{}|<>?,+=:"\/\\]{8,16}$
```

See this [regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/777GHN/1).